# How to add configure image name as variable in deployment file in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to create a codepipeline in aws , I am able to build my code , push image to ECR as well. then I want to rename the image in my deployment file that I have in git repo so that new deployment is created with the new image version.

Also If I keep same image then how will i deploy the deployment file in deploy stage in Kubernetes using aws codepipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to deploy different versions of the app in different environments - you can use [kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize). You can use codepipeline [variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html) to update the values.